# CodeLite clang code completion greyed out

Tags: clang, code-completion, codelite

I'm on Arch linux and I'm using codelite. Id like to enable the clang code completion, but the option to do so is greyed out, even though clang is installed. What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have clang installed during CodeLite building (for the libs), otherwise it will be greyed out.

I faced the same issue and had to compile CodeLite several times.

Answer (score 0):

If the option is disabled, it means that CodeLite was built with this option disabled.

By default clang code completion is enabled, unless it was specifically disabled by passing `-DENABLE_CLANG=0` to cmake before building CodeLite itself (or incase the package `libclang-dev` was missing during build)

You should contact the person who built CodeLite for Arch and ask him why did he disable clang code completion or build CodeLite by yourself from sources (a simple task on Linux)

Note that we (the CodeLite team) don't provide Arch binaries, so its probably someone from the Arch community.

About your last comment:
It is not relevant if you have clang installed or not (CodeLite uses `libclang.so` for code completion not the clang **compiler**) it only question of how was CodeLite built

Eran

Comment: The issue was just me compiling codelite before actually installing clang. :) Thank you!